# Host-Only Network not working on VMware Workstation

Tags: linux, windows-8, vmware-workstation

I installed WMware Workstation 9.0.2 on Windows 8 pro x64. I created an Oracle linux 6.4 virtual machine. I'm connecting to internet using only wireless on windows and my gateway is (192.168.1.1). When i use NAT connection, everything works fine and i can connect to internet on the linux vm but i have to use host-only network. I configured to virtual network editor like that

```
Vmnet1 
Type:Host-only 
DHCP:Enabled 
Subnet-Adress:192.168.2.0 
Subnet-Mask:255.255.255.0
```

I configured connection like that in linux vm

```
IPV4 Settings
Ip-Adress:192.168.2.2  
NetMask:255.255.255.0 
Gateway:192.168.2.1 
DNS:192.168.2.1
```

But i couldnt connect to internet. I disabled firewall and antivirus on windows but didnt work again. I'm sorry cant show you screen image because of my low reputation. Pls give me anyadvice. Thx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Host-only networking in VMware Workstation creates a network between all virtual machines (whose network type is set to host-only as well) and the host computer computer (in your case, your Windows 8 machine).

[This link](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_hostonly.html) provides more information on the topic of host-only networking.

If you're looking to provide internet connectivity, you can use either NAT Networking, or Bridged Networking.

NAT Networking will provide your GOS (Guest Operating System) with an IP that is NAT'ed from your Host. Bridged networking will allow your GOS to obtain an IP from your physical network (provided there's a DHCP -- usually your wired (or wireless) router serves as the DHCP server in most home networks). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

if your system is connected to wifi then go to Network Adapter>Setting>Bridged Automatic>Configure Adapter> Uncheck virtualBox Host-only Ethernet Adapter

Answer (score 0):

Came across this when I was having trouble with a host-only network on VMWare Workstation 12 (not player).

Although the current answer is pretty good I thought I would detail my own pain.

I have a Redhat VM which I set to (Static):

```
IP      - 192.168.1.101

Netmask - 255.255.255.0

Gateway - 192.168.1.1

DNS     - 192.168.1.1
```

My physical host is on `192.168.1.25` and is wireless like the OP.  I think the issue is that you when you chose the network to connect to in Workstation you have to turn off DHCP on the host-only network and set the range to the same as you are wanting to use.

For instance if you go to the virtual network editor (**Edit >> Virtual Network Editor**) and select **VMnet1** you will see it has a range at the bottom which you can change to (in my instance) `192.168.1.0`.  Put the mask as `255.255.255.0` and ***turn off*** '**Use local DHCP Service**....'.

Once I had done this I could talk to the image.  Make sure you try without firewalls/iptables on if you are still having issues.